# wsimport generate files including Jackson annotations

Tags: jackson, wsdl, jax-rs, jax-ws, wsimport

How can I use wsimport (or any other tool that provides similar funcionality for that matter) to generate the required files to talk to a JAX-WS webservice, but not only have it add JAXB annotation to the request/response classes, but also add Jackson annotations?

In the big picture, I do not want to duplicate, I want to reuse the generated classes for a REST service. If the above is not possible, is there any other way that saves me from duplicating everything?

Comment: AFAIK `Jackson` has a `JAXB Annotations` module, that can use `JAXB` annotated classes beside / instead of standard `Jackson` annotated ones...

Comment: If you create a response I'll accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, `Jackson` has a `JAXB Annotations` module, that can use `JAXB` annotated classes beside / instead of standard `Jackson` annotated ones...

See: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations